# Win8 Hyper-V guest's internet access thru "Internal Network"

Tags: networking, windows-8, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I am trying to connect a Win8-Hyper-V guest to the internet thru an "internal Network" per 
https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-15875

However even after enabling ICS the virtual switch on the host shows "No internet access" and the VM isn't able to connect to the internet.

[image]

I cannot create an "external Network" since our company router has Mac filtering and I'd not be able to connect to the internet after that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here's is configuring your virtual switch will actually start your internet

Here's a snapshot I have attached of the virtual switch. Instead of the wireless try changing the ip addresses of the virtual switch

[image: Virtual Switch]

If you don't find a virtual switch then go through this blog

it will help you to get one  for windows phone emulator

[Creating a virtual machine](http://moustafa-arafa.blogspot.in/2013/03/generic-failure-in-wp8-emulator-and.html)

Comment: There is no Wifi or windows phone involved here though. I have shared the internet connection of my physical NIC thru ICS. But the vEthernet[Hyper-V internal network] is still showing up as "disconnected".